# Is it possible to set MX records to receive emails in Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-email-settings-api

I have created a receiving email app with Google App Engine using the doc (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mail/receiving-mail-with-mail-api).

I want to receive emails using my custom domain. What should be mx settings? Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use a third party email service provider like Sendgrid to receive email at your GAE app.  GAE provides very limited email services.

Answer (score 0):

I have never configured MX records for App Engine. However, Internet mail does not know or care about App Engine.

Your MX record will look like this:

```
Type: MX
TTL: 86400
Preference: 10
mail server: Public IP address of your instance or the domain name.
```

Answer (score 0):

`email forwarding` is a feature of registars and mail servers, you cannot set this up in GCP without having setup a mail server first. If you use the free Gmail service to manage emails, [check this tutorial](https://www.thedigitalnonprofit.com/blog/use-gmail-own-domain-free) on how to proceed with some known registrar.